# What is the purpose of unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, qt, testing

For learning purposes, I dived into the field of unit testing. I've read through a few tutorials concerning this issue using QT, and came up with the following:

```
class QMyUnitTest : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    bool isPrime(unsigned int ui);
private Q_SLOTS:
    void myTest();
};

bool QMyUnitTest::isPrime(unsigned int n) {
    typedef std::map<unsigned int, bool> Filter;
    Filter filter;

    for(unsigned int ui = 2; ui <= n; ui++) {
        filter[ui] = true;
    }
    unsigned int ui = filter.begin()->first;
    for(Filter::iterator it = filter.begin();
        it != filter.end(); it++) {
        if(it->second) {
            for(unsigned int uj = ui * ui; uj <= n; uj += ui) {
                filter[uj] = false;
            }
        }
        ui++;
    }
    return filter[n];
}

void QMyUnitTest::myTest() {
}

QTEST_MAIN(QMyUnitTest)
#include "tst_myunittest.moc"
```

I know my prime finding algorithm is inefficient and especially flawed; it is meant this way. Now I want to test it thoroughly, but the following question arose:

**To test properly, do I not have to have a very precise idea of what could go wrong?**

Of course I can run through the first 1000 prime numbers and check if they come out `true` or 1000 not prime numbers and check if they come out `false`, but that might not catch the flaws in the algorithm (for example: `return filter[n];` is obviously horrible as `filter[n]` might not exist if `n<2`).

**What use is unit testing if I already have to know what potential problems of my function are?**

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to test?

Comment: Please revise your header to include something other than the tags used to describe your question. For example, "What is the purpose of unit testing?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The purpose of unit testing is to verify that the code you wrote actually does what it is supposed to do.

To write correct and complete tests, you need to know precisely what your code is supposed to do. You then write tests to verify:

- normal conditions (i.e. "normal", "usual" inputs produce the expected output)
- border conditions (i.e. input that is just barely within spec)
- failure conditions (i.e. you verify that your code fails correctly when the input is invalid).

Your example of testing the behavior of your `isPrime` routine with a numbers it doesn't handle is a good one. Without knowing your implementation, 0, 1, 2 and negative values would be good testcases for an `isPrime` routine - they are things you might not think about when implementing your algorithm, so they are valuable tests.

Note that verifying normal conditions isn't necessarily the easiest part. As in this case, making sure your algorithm is perfect requires a mathematical analysis, then a verification that your code implements that correctly - and this is sometimes hard. Checking a few hundred known values is not necessarily enough (it might start failing at the 101st value).

> What use is unit testing if I already have to know what potential problems of my function are?

You've got it reversed. Don't write your unit tests with your implementation code in mind. Write it with the specification in mind. Your code must fit the spec, and your tests must ensure that as much as they can. (Code coverage tools will help you find border conditions once the bulk of your testing is done.)

Comment: negative numbers would be no good instances for `unsigned int`s

Comment: +1 for writing the exact same sentence that I was working from: "You've got it reversed."

Comment: yes and no. Signed to unsigned conversions (or the other way around, or signed/unsigned comparisons) have bitten more than one C (or C++) developer in the past, and I don't see that changing any time soon. (In this specific case, `-1` would just input in there would just take a wee while to complete, assuming compiler warnings have been ignored)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed descriptions, I think I'm beginning to understand. You mentioned code coverage tools, and after searching for that I found quite a load of those. Do you happen to know a specific one that serves the purpose of getting started?

Comment: @nijansen: I simply use `gcov`, but there are indeed a lot of them out there. Depends on your toolchain and environment quite a bit.

Answer (score 10):

Just wanna add to what Mat already listed:

- Unit test will ensure that you and others who work on your code in the future won't change the behavior of your code by accident.
- If written correctly, Unit tests will be a great way to document the behavior of your code.

Comment: A little expansion on this important point: Code is never understood as well as during its first writeup. Unit tests are a way of writing down the knowledge about expected code behaviour in an automatically testable fashion. So, these unit tests are a message from you to future maintainers what you expected to go wrong or right.

Comment: Yup. Write tests as early as possible -- ideally *before* the implementation code that makes them pass.